# Pycharm not recognizing .robot file extensions

Tags: pycharm, robotframework

I am using Pycharm with Intellibot for Robot framework development.  I have created project and when I started to write code in .robot file it showing me errors for below code. Could you please help on this.. Thank you

```
*** Settings ***

Library  Selenium2Library

Library  OperatingSystem

Library  DateTime


*** Variables ***

${BROWSER}      chrome
```

Errors Are :

> Can't use starred expression here
>
> Statement expected, found Py:EXP
>
> Unresolved reference 'Settings'
>
> expression expected

I have added below Libraries :

```
pip                             20.2,
robotframework                  3.2.1,
robotframework-pythonlibcore    2.1.0,
robotframework-selenium2library 3.0.0,
robotframework-seleniumlibrary  4.5.0,
selenium                        3.141.0,
Selenium2LibraryExtension       1.1.0,
setuptools                      40.6.2,
urllib3                         1.25.10.
```

Comment: What happens when you execute your test(s)/robot files? Isn't it only your IDE compaining about something? Perhaps you need to set it up for a RF project. Have you searched for this?

Comment: This is most probably an issue with Intellibot plugin.. It hasnt been updated in sometime.